# Difference between InvariantCulture and Ordinal string comparison

Tags: c#, .net, string-comparison, ordinal

When comparing two strings in c# for equality, what is the difference between InvariantCulture and Ordinal comparison?

Comment: Maybe http://www.siao2.com/2004/12/29/344136.aspx ? (googled)

Comment: For those using `String1.Equals(String2, StringComparison.Ordinal)`, you better use `String1 == String2` which is intrinsically `String1.Equals(String2)` and it is by default an ordinal case-sensitive comparison.

Comment: @Ghasan Not sure if that makes `==` "better", but it is a) shorter, b) less explicit about what exactly it does and c) `String1` can be null without the comparison throwing a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Ghasan the official MSDN *Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework* page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121(v=vs.110).aspx#specifying_string_comparisons_explicitly) recommends the usage of overloads that explicitly specify the `StringComparison` type. In the case of string comparison, it means `String.Equals`.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky To avoid `NullReferenceException` you can simply use the static method: `String.Equals(string1, string2, StringComparison.Ordinal)`.

Answer (score 371, accepted):

### InvariantCulture

Uses a "standard" set of character orderings (a,b,c, ... etc.).  This is in contrast to some specific locales, which may sort characters in different orders ('a-with-acute' may be before ***or*** after 'a', depending on the locale, and so on).

### Ordinal

On the other hand, looks purely at the values of the raw byte(s) that represent the character.

---

There's a great sample at [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06.aspx) that shows the results of the various StringComparison values.  All the way at the end, it shows (excerpted):

```
StringComparison.InvariantCulture:
LATIN SMALL LETTER I (U+0069) is less than LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I (U+0131)
LATIN SMALL LETTER I (U+0069) is less than LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I (U+0049)
LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I (U+0131) is greater than LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I (U+0049)

StringComparison.Ordinal:
LATIN SMALL LETTER I (U+0069) is less than LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I (U+0131)
LATIN SMALL LETTER I (U+0069) is greater than LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I (U+0049)
LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I (U+0131) is greater than LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I (U+0049)
```

You can see that where InvariantCulture yields (U+0069, U+0049, U+00131), Ordinal yields (U+0049, U+0069, U+00131).

Comment: Ordinal comparison looks at the *code points*, not the bytes.

Comment: I feel like is useful information, but does not actually answer the question.  When determining *Equality* of two strings, is there any reason to use InvarintCulture instead of Ordinal?  It seems that InvariantCulture would be used to *Sort* strings, and Ordinal should be used for *Equality* checking (we don't care that accented-a comes before or after a, it's simply different).  Though, I myself am a little unsure of this point.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230117%28v=vs.90%29.aspx and notice that string normalization and ordinal comparison is recommended.

Comment: Ordinal is much quicker

Comment: @Joey seeing as .NET uses the same encoding for all strings (UTF-16) what's the difference between code points and bytes? Also the docs state *"Specifying the StringComparison.Ordinal or StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase value in a method call signifies a non-linguistic comparison in which the features of natural languages are ignored. Methods that are invoked with these StringComparison values base string operation decisions on simple byte comparisons"* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: There is good performance test results published [C# String Comparision Tests](http://rhale78.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/string-equality-and-performance-in-c/) which tells the performance of each different string comparision methods and their time.

Comment: [Official MSDN link for explaining the difference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb385972.aspx)

Comment: Concerning MPavlak's "unsure" comment above with (at this time) 106 upvotes, suggesting there is no difference between Ordinal and Invariant for equality checks, there actually is. They are different even for equality checks because of character expansion, as evidenced in another answer in this same thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20085219/88409

Comment: As this answer stands, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 371):

It does matter, for example - there is a thing called character expansion

```
var s1 = "Strasse";
var s2 = "Straße";

s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.Ordinal);           //false
s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);  //true
```

With `InvariantCulture` the ß character gets expanded to ss.

Comment: Does this thing also differ in some way between `Ordinal` and `InvariantCulture`? That's what the original question is about.

Comment: That's the only difference I have found so far when looking for differences in equality matching. Everything else is about character ordering.

Comment: For those that don't know `ß` it should be noted that `ß` at least in german equals to a double s, Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F

Comment: That's not quite correct @Peter, you cannot use `ß` and `ss` interchangeably in German (I'm a native speaker). There are cases where  both are legal (but often one is outdated / not recommended) and there are cases where only one form is allowed.

Comment: This simple example clearly demonstrates the difference between the 2 comparisons. I think I'm getting this now.

Comment: Had to try it: https://ideone.com/j8DvDo so cool! A little lesson in German as well. Wondering what's the difference between ß and ss now...

Comment: Also, "Æ" gets always expended to "AE" in InvariantCulture

Comment: Note that at least with .NET 5 both comparisons return false.

Comment: See related article here: [Behavior changes when comparing strings on .NET 5+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus).

Answer (score 167):

Pointing to [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx):

- Use `StringComparison.Ordinal` or `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` for comparisons as your safe default for culture-agnostic string matching.
- Use comparisons with `StringComparison.Ordinal` or `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` for better performance.
- Use the non-linguistic `StringComparison.Ordinal` or `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` values instead of string operations based on `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when the comparison is linguistically irrelevant (symbolic, for example).

And finally:

- **Do not use string operations based on `StringComparison.InvariantCulture` in most cases**. One of the few exceptions is when you are persisting linguistically meaningful but culturally agnostic data.

Answer (score 63):

Another handy difference (in English where accents are uncommon) is that an InvariantCulture comparison compares the entire strings by case-insensitive first, and then if necessary (and requested) distinguishes by case after first comparing only on the distinct letters.  (You can also do a case-insensitive comparison, of course, which won't distinguish by case.)  **Corrected:** Accented letters are considered to be another flavor of the same letters and the string is compared first ignoring accents and then accounting for them if the general letters all match (much as with differing case except not ultimately ignored in a case-insensitive compare).  This groups accented versions of the otherwise same word near each other instead of completely separate at the first accent difference.  This is the sort order you would typically find in a dictionary, with capitalized words appearing right next to their lowercase equivalents, and accented letters being near the corresponding unaccented letter.

An ordinal comparison compares strictly on the numeric character values, stopping at the first difference.  This sorts capitalized letters completely separate from the lowercase letters (and accented letters presumably separate from those), so capitalized words would sort nowhere near their lowercase equivalents.

InvariantCulture also considers capitals to be greater than lower case, whereas Ordinal considers capitals to be less than lowercase (a holdover of ASCII from the old days before computers had lowercase letters, the uppercase letters were allocated first and thus had lower values than the lowercase letters added later).

For example, by Ordinal: `"0" < "9" < "A" < "Ab" < "Z" < "a" < "aB" < "ab" < "z" < "Á" < "Áb" < "á" < "áb"`

And by InvariantCulture: `"0" < "9" < "a" < "A" < "á" < "Á" < "ab" < "aB" < "Ab" < "áb" < "Áb" < "z" < "Z"`

Comment: I took another look at this and noticed an inconsistency between the InvariantCulture example and my explanation on the handling of accented characters. The example appears to be correct, so I've corrected the explanation to be consistent. The InvariantCulture comparison does not stop at the first differing accent and appears to only consider an accent difference on the same letter if the rest of the strings match besides accents and case. An accent difference is then considered before an earlier case difference, so "Aaba" < "aába".

Answer (score 44):

Although the question is about *equality*, for quick visual reference, here the order of some strings *sorted* using a couple of cultures illustrating some of the idiosyncrasies out there.

```
Ordinal          0 9 A Ab a aB aa ab ss Ä Äb ß ä äb ぁ あ ァ ア 亜 Ａ
IgnoreCase       0 9 a A aa ab Ab aB ss ä Ä äb Äb ß ぁ あ ァ ア 亜 Ａ
--------------------------------------------------------------------
InvariantCulture 0 9 a A Ａ ä Ä aa ab aB Ab äb Äb ss ß ァ ぁ ア あ 亜
IgnoreCase       0 9 A a Ａ Ä ä aa Ab aB ab Äb äb ß ss ァ ぁ ア あ 亜
--------------------------------------------------------------------
da-DK            0 9 a A Ａ ab aB Ab ss ß ä Ä äb Äb aa ァ ぁ ア あ 亜
IgnoreCase       0 9 A a Ａ Ab aB ab ß ss Ä ä Äb äb aa ァ ぁ ア あ 亜
--------------------------------------------------------------------
de-DE            0 9 a A Ａ ä Ä aa ab aB Ab äb Äb ß ss ァ ぁ ア あ 亜
IgnoreCase       0 9 A a Ａ Ä ä aa Ab aB ab Äb äb ss ß ァ ぁ ア あ 亜
--------------------------------------------------------------------
en-US            0 9 a A Ａ ä Ä aa ab aB Ab äb Äb ß ss ァ ぁ ア あ 亜
IgnoreCase       0 9 A a Ａ Ä ä aa Ab aB ab Äb äb ss ß ァ ぁ ア あ 亜
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ja-JP            0 9 a A Ａ ä Ä aa ab aB Ab äb Äb ß ss ァ ぁ ア あ 亜
IgnoreCase       0 9 A a Ａ Ä ä aa Ab aB ab Äb äb ss ß ァ ぁ ア あ 亜
```

Observations:

- `de-DE`, `ja-JP`, and `en-US` sort the same way
- `Invariant` only sorts `ss` and `ß` differently from the above three cultures
- `da-DK` sorts quite differently
- the `IgnoreCase` flag matters for all sampled cultures

The code used to generate above table:

```
var l = new List<string>
    { "0", "9", "A", "Ab", "a", "aB", "aa", "ab", "ss", "ß",
      "Ä", "Äb", "ä", "äb", "あ", "ぁ", "ア", "ァ", "Ａ", "亜" };

foreach (var comparer in new[]
{
    StringComparer.Ordinal,
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase,
    StringComparer.InvariantCulture,
    StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase,
    StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("da-DK"), false),
    StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("da-DK"), true),
    StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("de-DE"), false),
    StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("de-DE"), true),
    StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("en-US"), false),
    StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("en-US"), true),
    StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("ja-JP"), false),
    StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("ja-JP"), true),
})
{
    l.Sort(comparer);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", l));
}
```

Comment: Hmmm - OK, it's nice that you did this research, and posted your findings, although I'm not exactly sure what your point is. Anyway, Danish may not be one of the "most important cultures" (although 5 million Danes are actually rather fond of their culture), but if you throw "aa" in as an additional test string, and "da-DK" in as an additional test culture, you'll see some interesting results.

Comment: @RenniePet Thanks for that. I added Danish, as it sorts quite differently than the 3 other cultures used. (As emoticons indicating irony don't seem to be as well-understood in the English language reading web as I would have assumed, I removed the "most important cultures" comment. After all, the BCL does not feature a `CultureComparer` which we could use to verify. For this table, the `Danish` culture(info) turned out to be very important.)

Comment: Thanks. I did realize that your "most important cultures" comment was intended to be taken with a grain of salt - it's just that I've gotten too old to use emoticons. I figure that texting has become so common that using emoticons is sort of like explaining your jokes after you tell them, irrespective of whether or not anyone laughs. Incidentally, the other Scandinavian cultures (Finnish, Norwegian and Swedish) are the same as Danish, except for the very special handling of "aa" - which proves that Danish is the superior culture, of course.

Comment: For what it's worth, Danish sorts ä and aa differently because of the location of the special letters æ (ae), ø (oe, ö), and å (aa, ä) at the end of the alphabet in the written order.

Answer (score 32):

Invariant is a linguistically appropriate type of comparison.
Ordinal is a binary type of comparison. (faster)
See http://www.siao2.com/2004/12/29/344136.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example where string equality comparison using InvariantCultureIgnoreCase and OrdinalIgnoreCase will not give the same results:

```
string str = "\xC4"; //A with umlaut, Ä
string A = str.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
//Length is 1, this will contain the single A with umlaut character (Ä)
string B = str.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
//Length is 2, this will contain an uppercase A followed by an umlaut combining character
bool equals1 = A.Equals(B, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
bool equals2 = A.Equals(B, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

If you run this, equals1 will be false, and equals2 will be true.

Comment: Just to add another similar example but with string literals, if `a="\x00e9"` (e acute) and `b="\x0065\x0301"` (e combined with an acute accent), `StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(a, b)` will return false while `StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Equals(a, b)` will return true.

Answer (score 4):

No need to use fancy unicode char exmaples to show the difference. Here's one simple example I found out today which is surprising, consisting of only ASCII characters.

According to the ASCII table, `0` (48, 0x30) is smaller than `_` (95, 0x5F) when compared ordinally. InvariantCulture would say the opposite (PowerShell code below):

```
PS> [System.StringComparer]::Ordinal.Compare("_", "0")
47
PS> [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCulture.Compare("_", "0")
-1
```

Comment: 0x48 is H, not 0. And "_" is 0x5F, not 0x95.

Answer (score -9):

Always try to use InvariantCulture in those string methods that accept it as overload. By using  InvariantCulture you are on a safe side. Many .NET programmers may not use this functionality but if your software will be used by different cultures, InvariantCulture is an extremely handy feature.

Comment: If your software will not be used by different cultures, it is much slower than Ordinal though.