# Partial Matching an ObservableCollection<string> Object

Tags: c#, .net

Ok let's say I have an `ObservableCollection<string>` object. Within this object I have a variety of strings:

```
SomeString01
SomeString-02
somestring-03
SOMESTRING.04
aString
```

I want to take an input, we'll call it `pattern` and store it as a string from a User interface, and do some partial matching on the `ObservableCollection`. I need do to partial matching on the collection, and everything is going to be case **insensitive**. In the end I want to these compiled into a brand new `ObservableCollection`. So here are some example cases:

```
pattern = "SoME"

// RESULTS:
SomeString01
SomeString-02
somestring-03
SOMESTRING.04

/* --- */

pattern = "-0"

// RESULTS:
SomeString-02
somestring-03

/* --- */

pattern = "ING0"

// RESULTS:
SomeString01

pattern = "s"

// RESULTS:
SomeString01
SomeString-02
somestring-03
SOMESTRING.04
aString
```

What is the best approach for this in a ClickOnce application?

Comment: can't you use a `.Where(x => <condition>)` on the collection?

Comment: @saurabh ... what is the best approach to do a case insensitive partial match on the collection. Did I do a poor job stating my question?

Comment: @Gabe I was trying to do that, but I'm having issues for case insensitivity. So I figured I was doing something the hard way / wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I actually dug around more with Google, and found a better solution:

You could use IndexOf() and pass StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase

```
string title = "STRING";
bool contains = title.IndexOf("string", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

Even better is defining a new extension method for string:

```
public static bool Contains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp)
{
    return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
}

string title = "STRING";
bool contains = title.Contains("string", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Contributed by: [JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar)

Source: [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring/444818#444818)

---

SO now I have implemented it in my source as follows:

```
foreach (string source in SourceStrings)
{
    // Code for some pre-reqs here

    if (source.IndexOf(Pattern, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
        subset.Add(source);
    }

    // Finish up anything else I had to do here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Gabes answer in the comments.

but slightly more specific

```
.Where(x => x.IndexOf("Some",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
```

Comment: What would be the difference of using that versus `.Where(x => x.IndexOf(pattern, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase >= 0)` ? Or is this 6 one way, half a dozen the other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492799/difference-between-invariantculture-and-ordinal-string-comparision is a good writeup.. I don't know how to post links in comments yet effectively. Pretty much 6 one way, half a dozen the other