# Why does OrdinalIgnoreCase and InvariantCultureIgnoreCase return different results?

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I thought `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` and `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` do the same job when it comes to English-only strings. However it's not the case in the following code that I'm working on:

```
// Returns 0
string.Compare("877495169FA05B9D8639A0EBC42022338F7D2324","‎877495169fa05b9d8639a0ebc42022338f7d2324", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

// Returns -1
string.Compare("877495169FA05B9D8639A0EBC42022338F7D2324","‎877495169fa05b9d8639a0ebc42022338f7d2324", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Is there a particular reason why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between InvariantCulture and Ordinal string comparision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492799/difference-between-invariantculture-and-ordinal-string-comparision)

Comment: @DanielA.White This question is most certainly _not_ a duplicate of that question. I think you didn't read this one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
"‎877495169fa05b9d8639a0ebc42022338f7d2324"
```

Sounds like a trick question.  There's an extra character at the start at this string, before the first digit 8.  It isn't visible in the browser.  It is U+200E, "Left to Right Mark".  The ordinal comparison sees that character, the invariant comparison ignores it.  You can see it for yourself by using ToCharArray() on the string.

Delete that string and paste this one instead, I removed U+200E from it:

```
"877495169fa05b9d8639a0ebc42022338f7d2324"
```

And the Compare() method now returns 0 like it should.  Do watch out for that text editor or IME you are using right now.  Isn't Unicode fun?

Comment: Nicely spotted. In my Notepad++ it shows up as a question mark: `"?877495169fa05b9d8639a0ebc42022338f7d2324"`.

Comment: Thank you! It's not a trick question, I actually copied this string as the thumbprint of a certificate from certmgr.msc to my program, and failed the comparison. I had no idea that could contain invisible characters. Turns out Visual Studio doesn't show those characters as well. It is fun!

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense.  For the record: what language version of Windows produced this?

Comment: Windows 8 Enterprise en-US.