# Alter Sort-Object behavior

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

When working with a drive mapped to a Linux share, filenames are case sensitive. PowerShell handles this as expected, but I'd like to sort the output in a manner analogous to the sort order used in the "C" locale, which means sorting by character value in ascending order from U+0000 all the way through U+10FFFF (e.g. '0foo' comes before 'Foo' and 'Foo' comes before 'bar' and 'bar' comes before 'foo')

To illustrate the problem:

```
PS > gci Z:\foo | sort -casesensitive
xyz
Xyz
XYZ
yZ
YZ
```

Output desired:

```
XYZ
Xyz
YZ
xyz
yZ
```

I tried setting the current thread's culture variables to `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture`, but I had no success:

```
$thrd = [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread
$thrd.CurrentCulture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$thrd.CurrentUICulture = $thrd.CurrentCulture
```

Am I even close when I assume it has to do with the culture info, or am I really far off track? Does anybody have any idea where I should start? I'm guessing I need to temporarily create a CultureInfo instance that has the behavior I desire, but it only has getters as far as CompareInfo goes, not to mention I'm unsure of how to overload the CompareInfo.Compare function that Sort-Object requires using PowerShell functions. Or is this effectively a lost cause because that isn't possible?

*Edit*

At the very least, would it be possible to sort with uppercase characters first, as in XYZ, Xyz, xyz, YZ, yZ?

Comment: 'Ordinal' is the comparison in .NET that compares characters based on their code point values (see also [Difference between InvariantCulture and Ordinal string comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/a/492885/2495)). [Mitul's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18544765/2495) with [`[StringComparer]::Ordinal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinal.aspx) looks like the best choice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried really hard to find if there is a way to alter the `sort-object` method itself but not working.  But something similar I was able to accomplish using StringComparer static class as demonstrated in this [**msdn example**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase.aspx).

To answer your last part,

```
At the very least, would it be possible to sort with uppercase characters first, as in XYZ, Xyz, xyz, YZ, yZ?
```

`[System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` is your answer. To see the differences I have tried all the different versions below.

```
$arr = "0foo","xyz","Xyz","YZ","yZ","XYZ","Foo","bar" 
$list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$list.AddRange($arr)

Write-host "CurrentCulture"
$list.Sort([System.StringComparer]::CurrentCulture);
$list
<# --------CurrentCulture--------
CurrentCulture
0foo
bar
Foo
xyz
Xyz
XYZ
yZ
YZ
#>

Write-Host "CurrentCultureIgnoreCase"
$list.Sort([System.StringComparer]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
$list

<# --------CurrentCultureIgnoreCase--------
CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
0foo
bar
Foo
XYZ
Xyz
xyz
YZ
yZ
#>

Write-Host "InvariantCulture"
$list.Sort([System.StringComparer]::InvariantCulture);
$list
<# --------InvariantCulture--------
InvariantCulture
0foo
bar
Foo
xyz
Xyz
XYZ
yZ
YZ
#>

Write-Host "InvariantCultureIgnoreCase"
$list.Sort([System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
$list

<# --------InvariantCultureIgnoreCase--------

InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
0foo
bar
Foo
XYZ
Xyz
xyz
YZ
yZ
#>

Write-Host "Ordinal"
$list.Sort([System.StringComparer]::Ordinal);
$list

<# --------Ordinal--------
Ordinal
0foo
Foo
XYZ
Xyz
YZ
bar
xyz
yZ
#>

Write-Host "OrdinalIgnoreCase"
$list.Sort([System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase);
$list

<# --------OrdinalIgnoreCase--------
OrdinalIgnoreCase
0foo
bar
Foo
xyz
XYZ
Xyz
yZ
YZ
#>
```

Comment: Very thorough. I was hoping I wouldn't need to do anything like this, but apparently the idea of sorting is rather limited, even in PowerShell. Thank you very much.