# Powershell - Sorting string objects with a special character

Tags: powershell, sorting

I'm running

```powershell
'S-tst','ssrst','srst2','s-zaa','s-a','s-zf' | Sort-Object
```

Shouldn't I have gotten a return of

```
s-a
S-tst
s-zaa
s-zf
srst2
ssrst
```

but instead I get the following:

```
s-a
srst2
ssrst
S-tst
s-zaa
s-zf
```

How is this possible ? Does sort-object only look at letters when sorting out ? Is there any way to sort it out by special characters ?

Comment: Interesting spot.  Looks like MS Office has the same quirk; though it's by design.  http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/156283-Have-I-found-a-sorting-error-in-Excel

Comment: May be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734016/powershell-sort-of-strings-with-underscores ?

Comment: Sourcecode: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/a291834f39a3de45b78e38153b3bafdf45f081a6/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/sort-object.cs

Comment: MS uses a `Word Sort` algorithm.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318144(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Suggested improvement: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4098

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate (although related).  The other post is asking how to sort by Ascii order.  This is asking how to disable the work sorting.

Answer (score 5):

This behaviour is by design, but not always what people want/expect.  If you want strings sorted with each character in ASCII order use this:

```powershell
Add-Type @"
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;

    public class SimpleStringComparer: IComparer, IComparer<string>
    {

        private static readonly CompareInfo compareInfo = CompareInfo.GetCompareInfo(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Name);

        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            return Compare(x as string, y as string);
        }
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            return compareInfo.Compare(x, y, CompareOptions.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
        public SimpleStringComparer() {}
    }
"@


[string[]]$myList = 's-a','s-a1','s''a','s''a1', 'sa','sa1','s^a','S-a','S-a1','S''a','S''a1', 'Sa','Sa1','S^a'

[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$list.AddRange($myList)
[SimpleStringComparer]$comparer = [SimpleStringComparer]::new()
$list.Sort([SimpleStringComparer]::new())
$list
```

Outputs:

```
s'a
S'a
s'a1
S'a1
s-a
S-a
s-a1
S-a1
sa
Sa
sa1
Sa1
s^a
S^a
```

**More Info**

Per *@TessellatingHeckler* in the comments, you can sort strings in character code (ordinal) order by casting the string to a char array.  However, that still handles hyphens and apostrophes in a potentially unexpected way (as these characters are ignored):

```powershell
$myList = 's-a','s-a1','s''a','s''a1', 'sa','sa1','s^a','S-a','S-a1','S''a','S''a1', 'Sa','Sa1','S^a'
$myList | Sort-Object -Property { [char[]] $_ }
```

```
s'a
S'a
s-a
S-a
s'a1
S'a1
s-a1
S-a1
s^a
S^a
sa
Sa
sa1
Sa1
```

The current sorting behaviour is by design.  It appears that PowerShell implements a "Word Sort".  This is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318144(v=vs.85).aspx#SortingFunctions

In addition to ignoring hyphens and apostrophes (except when comparing otherwise identical strings), this sort also treats punctuation characters as coming before alphanumerics, and handles accented letters alongside their counterparts.  A simple demo of this can be seen like so:

```
32..255 | %{[string][char][byte]$_} | sort
```

To define other sorting behaviours, currently you'd likely need to dip into .Net, like so:

```powershell
Add-Type @"
```

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Collections;
    public class NumericStringComparer: IComparer
    {
        //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
        [DllImport("shlwapi.dll")]
        public static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            return Compare(x as string, y as string);
        }
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
        }
        public NumericStringComparer() {}
    }
```

```powershell
"@

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$myList = 's-a','s-a1','s''a','s''a1', 'sa','sa1','s^a','S-a','S-a1','S''a','S''a1', 'Sa','Sa1','S^a', , '100a','1a','001a','2a','20a'
$myList.Sort([NumericStringComparer]::new())
$myList -join ', '
```

The above sorts strings the way Windows Explorer would (i.e. treating leading digits as numeric values):

```
s'a, s'a1, S'a, s-a, S-a, S-a1, S'a1, s-a1, S^a, s^a, 1a, 001a, 2a, Sa, Sa1, sa, sa1, 20a, 100a
```

I've submitted a feature suggestion to provide more PS friendly solutions on `Sort-Object`.  See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4098

Comment: Here is a [Jon Skeet explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886555/unexpected-behavior-when-sorting-strings-with-letters-and-dashes) of the sorting behavior. As far as I can tell, `Sort-Object` accepts a `-Culture` parameter, but there is no culture I can find with an Ordinal sort, and creating a new custom culture requires admin rights and registering it system-wide before it can be used, so that leaves PS a bit stuck.

Comment: `$a = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@('srs', 's-a', 's-z'); $a.Sort([System.StringComparer]::Ordinal)` - from https://stackoverflow.com/q/18543842/478656 (possibly makes this Q a duplicate)

Comment: Can you clarify that `Sort-Object -Property { [char[]] $_ }` is not a fix, but a demonstration of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve ASCII-style order by sorting string hex representation:

```
'S-tst','ssrst','srst2','s-zaa','s-a','s-zf' | Sort-Object {Format-Hex -InputObject $_}
```

In case you need it case insensitive you can lowercase is first:

```
'S-tst','ssrst','srst2','s-zaa','s-a','s-zf' | Sort-Object {Format-Hex -InputObject $_.ToLower()}
```