# SortedList throwing exception when adding french characters

Tags: c#, special-characters, sortedlist

I am adding some unique french words to a sorted list, but it doesn't seem to differentiate certain words like "bœuf" & boeuf".

```
private static void TestSortedList()
{

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-fr");
    SortedList sortedList = new SortedList(new Comparer(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));

    try
    {
        sortedList.Add("bœuf", "Value1");
        sortedList.Add("boeuf", "Value1");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

So the following code above throws exception "System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added."
Please help!

Comment: But isn't that what it's supposed to do? When sorting in French those two words are considered the same.

Comment: Hi George - is there a way to make .NET consider them not same while sorting? I need to build a list & these 2 words must appear in the final list.

Comment: See the answer below on how you can make it do that, this question explains why. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492799/difference-between-invariantculture-and-ordinal-string-comparision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SortedList sortedList = new SortedList(StringComparer.Ordinal);

    try
    {
        sortedList.Add("bœuf", "Value1");
        sortedList.Add("boeuf", "Value1");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
```

works. To explain, the `Ordinal` and `OrdinalIgnoreCase` comparers compare the characters bytes and they are different for different chars.
See [Difference between InvariantCulture and Ordinal string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492799/difference-between-invariantculture-and-ordinal-string-comparision) too.

Comment: This works, of course, but it's difficult to know if this is acceptable for the OP. By not using French sorting the ordering of the SortedList will be different, for example if the first characters of some words are accented.

Comment: That's right, I edited my post to explain the `Ordinal` comparer so he can think about if it fits or not.