# Difference between LastIndexOf('string') vs LastIndexOf('string')OrdincalComparison

Tags: c#

What is the difference between

This

```
var ext = name.LastIndexOf(@".");
```

and This

```
var ext = name.LastIndexOf(@".", System.StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/492799/961113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `StringComparison` enum documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> An operation that uses ordinal sort rules performs a comparison based on the numeric value (Unicode code point) of each Char in the string. An ordinal comparison is fast but culture-insensitive. When you use ordinal sort rules to sort strings that start with Unicode characters (U+), the string U+xxxx comes before the string U+yyyy if the value of xxxx is numerically less than yyyy.

The extra parameter is telling the method how to compare strings. With `Ordinal`, it's going to use unicode code points for the comparison. Other values of the enum use the culture (invariant or the current one) and can use case insensitive comparison.