# confused to use String.Compare?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2013, compareto

I use String.Compare like below sample

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int result = String.Compare("A", "a");
        Console.Write(result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

but , when run the program , result is **1** . but i except result will be **-1** .
i use vs 2013 .

Comment: I use  C#  language . (vs2013)

Comment: I bet hjpotter92 was talking about locales. Anyhow in the first edition of the question it was "A" and "b", now it's "A" and "a".

Comment: Yes , now is right . but when i run program , i except result will be -1 but result is 1 ?! why ?

Comment: (specifically http://stackoverflow.com/a/529430/11683)

Comment: I am also assuming it has to do with locales ... in dotnetfiddle it yields 1 https://dotnetfiddle.net/U9XqkJ

Comment: @okaram It yields 1 for the OP too.

Comment: In addition to reading through duplicate question, please also carefully review [Best Practices for Using Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#the_details_of_string_comparison) on MSDN (which linked from `String.Compare` documentation for your convenience).

Answer (score -2):

Your expectation is wrong.
String.Compare(str1, str2)
if the str1 is greater than str2 then the result is greater than zero and 
if the str1 is less than str2 then the result is less than zero and 
if the str1 is equals str2 then the result is zero

Comment: Exactly. The OP knows that and rightfully expects "a" to be greater than "A". But it is the other way round.