# String.StartsWith not working with Asian languages?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I've noticed this strange issue. Check out this Vietnamese (according to [Google Translate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate)) string:

```
string line = "Mìng-dĕ̤ng-ngṳ̄";
string sub = "Mìng-dĕ̤ng-ngṳ";
line.Length
15
sub.Length
14
line.StartsWith(sub)
false
```

Which seems to me like a **wrong** result. So, I've implemented my custom `StartWith` function, which compares the string *char-by-char*.

```
public bool CustomStartWith(string parent, string child)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < child.Length; i++)
    {
        if (parent[i] != child[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And as I assumed, the results of running this function

```
CustomStartWith("Mìng-dĕ̤ng-ngṳ̄", "Mìng-dĕ̤ng-ngṳ")
true
```

What's going on here?! How's this possible?

Comment: Use an invariant culture. See, for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/q/492799/1364007

Comment: I don't know Vietnamese. There is a line over the last 'u'. Does that not make it a different letter? *Edit:* I missed that you're printing the lengths, which seems to show that the line is considered *another* character... interesting.

Comment: Seems to me that `StartsWith()` SHOULD be returning false, because (as Jonathon points out), `line` does not actually start with `sub`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Maybe, maybe not. You really need a Vietnamese speaker to decide that (and I assume that even within that community you can argue for both cases. This looks to me like the ä vs a vs ae in German -- for which the answer can only be: it depends.... )

Comment: If you copy&paste the u with line on top to notepad++ it actually displays 2 characters (with utf-8), if you paste it to notepad it displays with the upper line but you need 2 backspaces to delete it..

Comment: @Thilo No, it really is different. The last `u` is a different letter. And also, to see the true length you need to use `new StringInfo(line).LengthInTextElements` which returns 13, not the 15 that string.Length returns.

Comment: I understand that. ä and ae are also two different letters. But maybe you want to treat them the same for ordering strings, maybe you don't.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen When I paste `ṳ̄` to notepad++, it displays only the single `ṳ̄` character... We must have different settings.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The result returned by `StartsWith` is correct. By default, most string comparison methods perform culture-sensitive comparisons using the current culture, not plain byte sequences. Although your `line` starts with a byte sequence identical to `sub`, the substring it represents is not equivalent under most (or all) cultures.

If you really want a comparison that treats strings as plain byte sequences, use the overload:

```
line.StartsWith(sub, StringComparison.Ordinal);                       // true
```

If you want the comparison to be case-insensitive:

```
line.StartsWith(sub, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);             // true
```

Here's a more familiar example:

```
var line1 = "café";   // 63 61 66 E9     – precomposed character 'é' (U+00E9)
var line2 = "café";   // 63 61 66 65 301 – base letter e (U+0065) and
                      //                   combining acute accent (U+0301)
var sub   = "cafe";   // 63 61 66 65 
Console.WriteLine(line1.StartsWith(sub));                             // false
Console.WriteLine(line2.StartsWith(sub));                             // false
Console.WriteLine(line1.StartsWith(sub, StringComparison.Ordinal));   // false
Console.WriteLine(line2.StartsWith(sub, StringComparison.Ordinal));   // true
```

In the above examples, `line2` starts with the same byte sequence as `sub`, followed by a combining acute accent (U+0301) to be applied to the final `e`. `line1` uses the [precomposed character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character) for `é` (U+00E9), so its byte sequence does not match that of `sub`.

In real-world semantics, one would typically not consider `cafe` to be a substring of `café`; the `e` and `é` are treated as distinct characters. That `é` happens to be represented as a pair of characters starting with `e` is an internal implementation detail of the encoding scheme (Unicode) that should not affect results. This is demonstrated by the above example contrasting `café` and `café`; one would not expect different results unless specifically intending an ordinal (byte-by-byte) comparison.

Adapting this explanation to your example:

```
string line = "Mìng-dĕ̤ng-ngṳ̄";   // 4D EC 6E 67 2D 64 115 324 6E 67 2D 6E 67 1E73 304
string sub  = "Mìng-dĕ̤ng-ngṳ";   // 4D EC 6E 67 2D 64 115 324 6E 67 2D 6E 67 1E73
```

Each .NET character represents a UTF-16 code unit, whose values are shown in the comments above. The first 14 code units are identical, which is why your char-by-char comparison evaluates to true (just like `StringComparison.Ordinal`). However, the 15th code unit in `line` is the combining macron, ◌̄  ([U+0304](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/304/index.htm)), which combines with its preceding `ṳ` ([U+1E73](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1E73/index.htm)) to give `ṳ̄`.

Comment: But what is a default comparer for StartsWith? Also, why do you use IgnoreCase but not just Ordinal? Author uses ordinal comparation without ignoring case.

Comment: @VadimMartynov: I've updated the example to use `Ordinal`. Expanding explanation.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `line1.StartsWith(line2)` is true (and vice versa), as does `line1.Equals(line2, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)` [and CurrentCulture for most reasonable settings... the single-argument Equals seems to use Ordinal]

Answer (score 9):

This is not a bug. The `String.StartsWith` is in fact much smarter than just a character-by-character check of your two strings. It takes into account your current culture (language settings, etc.) and it takes into account contractions and special characters. (It does not care you need two characters to end up with `ṳ̄`. It compares it as one).

So this means that if you don't want to take all those culture specific settings, and just want to check it using ordinal comparison, you have to tell the comparer that.

This is the correct way to do that (not ignoring the case, like [Douglas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34741274/993547) did!):

```
line.StartsWith(sub, StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

Comment: But why wouldn't you want to take these culture-specific settings into account? I don't speak Vietnamese, should these two Strings be considered prefix-equal or not?

Comment: That is to OP. I don't know Vietnames either, but I can understand that you sometimes want to compare one way and the next time the other way. That is why you can influence comparison using `Ordinal`.

Comment: I understand. All I'm saying is that OP should carefully consider if that is really the way to go.

Comment: I don't think that this is actually culture-specific - they won't be considered the same in _any_ locale.

Comment: @Thilo do you maybe speak English or another European language? In those languages one normally considers letters and diacritics as units with a few exceptions (and most of those exceptions are considering are combining letters, not splitting them). We'd normally say `naïve` and `naï̈ve` both have 5 letters and `façade` and `façade` both have 6. .NET accordingly considers the first two to `StartsWith` each other and likewise the second two, but gives `Length` of 5, 6, 6 & 7 accordingly.