# C# String.IndexOf - Text with special character returning wrong result

Tags: c#, special-characters, indexof

`"* {{IPA|ɪntɹəvaɪtl}}̩".IndexOf("}}")` returns -1.

`"* {{IPA|ɪntɹəvaɪtl}}".IndexOf("}}")` returns 18.

I expect the first sample to return 18.

Notice there is a special character U+0329 following the ending double brackets in the first sample.

Combining Vertical Line Below U+0329

Why is it returning -1 instead of 18? Even in an ordinal search, the string contains "}}", so it should not return -1.

Comment: I wonder if it's culture related. What if you try `"foo".IndexOf("", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: -1 means it didn't find a match and if there is an extra hidden character in the search string that isn't in the string you are searching then a match will not be found.

Comment: Yes, I already know that. The hidden character follows the closing brackets, so it should return 18.

Comment: The hidden character comes after }}

Comment: Evan, your comment helped, I tried StringComparison.Ordinal and it worked as expected. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone interested there's some good info in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492799/difference-between-invariantculture-and-ordinal-string-comparison

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between InvariantCulture and Ordinal string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492799/difference-between-invariantculture-and-ordinal-string-comparison)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Not the same question. Answer works, but my question still remains, why does IndexOf returns -1 when there is {{ in the search string, being it's an ordinal search?

Comment: “Duplicate” means the answer is a duplicate, not the question. U+0329 is a combining character, it changes the preceding character; `"}" + "\u0329"` is a single glyph different from "}", it is not a string of two glyphs.

Comment: The link above mentions nothing about glyphs. But thanks for the explanation. Your comment answers my question. Keep flagging away, your marshal badge is almost there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(NB: I am not a Unicode guru.)

The issue may be that the character U+0329 is a combining character.  If you replace the `}}` in the string with alphabetic characters you'll see the issue a little more clearly:

```
"the̩"
```

Note that in this case U+0329 has appeared as a modifier on the `e` in the string, altering the character's visual representation.  The same is happening, albeit strangely, with the `}}` character pair.

What you have is not a pair of *RIGHT CURLY BRACKET* characters, it's one *RIGHT CURLY BRACKET* and one *RIGHT CURLY BRACKET + COMBINING VERTICAL LINE BELOW* **glyph**.  When you compare this using the default `StringComparison` option then the second *RIGHT CURLY BRACKET* in your search string doesn't match because it is being matched against a glyph (sequence of characters) that is different.

Using `StringComparison.Ordinal` however changes the way that the Unicode is processed, ignoring the *COMBINING* attribute of U+0329 and simply comparing the code points.

---

Where this gets interesting is when you're searching for accented characters, since there are often multiple glyphs that look the same and *compare* the same when using `CurrentCulture` or `InvariantCulture` but are composed differently.

Take for example the *LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE* "`é`" code point U+00E9 compared to the glyph *LATIN SMALL LETTER E + COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT* (U+0065, U+0301) "`é`".  They look the same and compare the same when you use `InvariantCulture` but not when you use `Ordinal` comparison.

You can do a lot of work just trying to define what is the 'right' way to handle this, let alone implementing that way.  I often find it's better to simply accept that some character sequences are going to give you trouble and pick one `StringComparison` value to go with.

Comment: Thanks. That's the answer I was looking for.