# Why is case-insensitive HashSet<T> performance so bad

Tags: c#, performance, hashset

Why is `HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` (`Perf_HashSet_CaseInsensitive`) perf'ing (performing) so bad? The `Perf_HashSet` workaround is perf'ing 20x comparatively.

```
// perf Contains(): 1M iterations, 25 size (unsuccessful lookup)
Test                         Duration (ms)
Perf_HashSet                            43 <-
Perf_Dictionary                         49 
Perf_HybridDictionary                   63 
Perf_ListDictionary                    223 
Perf_List                              225 
Perf_HashSet_CaseInsensitive           903 <-
```

code:

```cs
// <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
[TestFixture]
public class ContainsPerfTests
{
    private const int iterations = 1_000_000;
    private const int size = 25;

    [Test]
    [Explicit]
    public void Perf_List()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            list.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
        }
        var x = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            var contains = list.Contains(x.ToLowerInvariant());
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    [Test]
    [Explicit]
    public void Perf_HashSet()
    {
        var hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            hashSet.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
        }
        var x = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            var contains = hashSet.Contains(x.ToLowerInvariant());
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    [Test]
    [Explicit]
    public void Perf_HashSet_CaseInsensitive()
    {
        var hashSetCaseInsensitive = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            hashSetCaseInsensitive.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
        }
        var x = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            var contains = hashSetCaseInsensitive.Contains(x);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    [Test]
    [Explicit]
    public void Perf_Dictionary()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            dictionary.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLowerInvariant(), false);
        }
        var x = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            var contains = dictionary.ContainsKey(x.ToLowerInvariant());
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    [Test]
    [Explicit]
    public void Perf_HybridDictionary()
    {
        var hybridDictionary = new HybridDictionary(caseInsensitive: true);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            hybridDictionary.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLowerInvariant(), null);
        }
        var x = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            var contains = hybridDictionary.Contains(x);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    [Test]
    [Explicit]
    public void Perf_ListDictionary()
    {
        var listDictionary = new ListDictionary();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            listDictionary.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLowerInvariant(), null);
        }
        var x = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            var contains = listDictionary.Contains(x.ToLowerInvariant());
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `OrdinalIgnoreCase` to make a fair test? `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` performs a culture-aware comparison using the rules of the invariant culture.

Comment: They don't behave the same, so their performance characteristics aren't relevant.

Comment: Also you're not counting the memory allocations you're creating with your `ToLower...()` calls, you will have to pay for those later with GC collections.

Comment: It seems redundant to use an ignore case comparator and also insert elements using  the toLower()

Comment: @Blindy You have to pay the collection costs *for the strings that can actually be collected*.  If in the actual code in question the original strings will stay rooted then you're increasing the memory footprint, not [just] adding GC pressure.

Comment: @Charlie inserting elements using toLower() is just to keep the setup the same for all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason for this big difference in performance is because you are using a culture-sensitive comparison for the case-insensitive hash set, whereas the case-sensitive hash set uses an ordinal one.

Without passing the hash set any equality comparers, the hash set uses the default equality comparer of that type, which calls the [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-5.0#System_String_Equals_System_String_) method. Notice that `String.Equals`

> performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison.

Whereas `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`:

> performs a case-insensitive string comparison using the word comparison rules of the invariant culture.

It is important to note that "invariant culture" is not the same as "culture-insensitive", or "ordinal":

Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(
"ss", "ß")); // true
Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(
"ss", "ß")); // false

The invariant culture still has collation rules, and looking up and applying those rules takes time.

Changing `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` to `OrdinalIgnoreCase` should make the execution time almost the same. That doesn't mean there aren't other problems with your benchmark, as the comments have pointed out.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492799/difference-between-invariantculture-and-ordinal-string-comparison