# Full string comparison rules in C#

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, localization

Where do I find the exact and complete string comparison rules for a certain culture in C#?
Example:
With `StringComparer.InvariantCulture` the strings "Masse" and "Maße" are equal.
There needs to be list of rules.

There have been similar questions, like:
[Difference between InvariantCulture and Ordinal string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492799/difference-between-invariantculture-and-ordinal-string-comparison)
This explains the concepts and gives examples. But I would like to have the source where the actual rules are defined.

Comment: "There needs to be list of rules." heh; no, not really - at least, not exhaustively; also: `StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Equals("Masse", "Maße")` returns `false` for me... do you mean sort compares, i.e. `Compare`? Because that returns `-1` for me; note: if it returned `0`, it wouldn't mean "they are equal" - it would mean "they should be sorted similarly"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between InvariantCulture and Ordinal string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492799/difference-between-invariantculture-and-ordinal-string-comparison)

Comment: @MarcGravell  
Just tried again:
  bool b = StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Equals("Masse", "Maße");
is `true` in .Net Framework 4.8.

Comment: @emagers: Only partially, although it goes in the right direction. Still it only gives some examples.

Comment: This article explains differences between the "old" Framework and .NET 5+: [Behavior changes when comparing strings on .NET 5+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus).

Comment: Maybe for deeper digging into this topic the MS documention for how things should be used [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings)

Comment: It uses ICU now, see https://icu.unicode.org/home for full details.

Answer (score 0):

For C#, this has historically varied depending on which version and flavor of C# and what OS you're running on.

Olivier's comment is an excellent current source of information: [Behavior changes when comparing strings on .NET 5+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus).

I expect this unification of C# on all platforms based on ICU to be stable.

ICU is an API that is driven by data from the [Unicode CLDR](https://cldr.unicode.org/) project. So the precise mappings and equivalences in your example are ultimately derived from CLDR.